# Copy Contents if Match not found in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using the following formula

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$6,MATCH($D2,$B$2:$B$6,0),1)
```

To create `colD` with matching `item_ids` from the `model_num` in `colC`. The problem is when it doesn't find a matching `model_num` in `colC` then it puts `#N/A` in `colD`.

```
item_id (colA)   model_num (colB)   data (colC)         new_data (colD)
--------         ----------         -------             ----------
870834           FD021              FD1424B             10752514
16595156         S3TA03B            Not Required        #N/A
10752514         FD1424B            S3TA03B             16595156
10756167         SU03B              Included with Kit   #N/A
14667130         KDAD               SU03B               10756167
```

If it doesn't find a match it should just copy what is already in `colC` to `colD`.

```
item_id (colA)   model_num (colB)   data (colC)         new_data (colD)
--------         ----------         -------             ----------
870834           FD021              FD1424B             10752514
16595156         S3TA03B            Not Required        Not Required
10752514         FD1424B            S3TA03B             16595156
10756167         SU03B              Included with Kit   Included with Kit
14667130         KDAD               SU03B               10756167
```

**The Question**
When the formula doesn't find a match in `colC` how can I tell it to just copy the contents of `colC` to `colD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula doesn't work, I assume you need a MATCH function in there....also I assume the lookup value should be C2 as the formula goes in D2 - like this

`=INDEX($A$2:$B$6,MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B$6,0),1)`

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2007 or later you can use IFERROR to get what you want, i.e. this version in D2 copied down

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$6,MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B$6,0),1),$C2)`

...or in any version

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B$6,0)),$C2,INDEX($A$2:$B$6,MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B$6,0),1))`

Comment: yep. that was a mistake. and the IFERROR was perfect. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2007 or later, you can just wrap your formula in an `IFERROR()` function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(...),C2)
```